# Django - Diplay a form in a modal

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, bootstrap-modal

I'm building a Django application and I try to display one of my forms in a modal window. It has been initially developed for a normal one, the scripts worked fine, but I cannot manage implement properly the modal.
The context is classical: a window displays a list of objects with, for each of them, a button to edit it, and an additional global button to create a new object. Each button is supposed to open the same modal.
It could have become easy if I did not have several js scripts dedicated to the form, because they are my issue: the do not work properly now that the form is in a modal. So there is something I did wrong, and at the end I'm not even sure my approach is the best one.

First question: among my search, an idea could be that js script won't apply on html part updated afterwards: is it true? In this case, is there a way to make a kind of 'reload' to make js undertand its scope has changed?

The modal is displayed using bootstrap, HTML code is the following:

```html
<div id="grp_detail" class="modal fade hide" role="dialog" tabindex='-1'>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content form_content">
            {% include './adm_group_detail.html' %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tell me if you need the included template - it's quite big because the form is a bit tricky.

The view that displays de page with the list is the following:

```py
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser or (u.id is not None and u.usercomp.is_admin))
def adm_groups(request, comp_slug):
    '''
        Manage users groups
    '''
    # Variables set to be integrated in locals()
    company = Company.get_company(comp_slug)
    group_list = UserGroup.objects.filter(company__comp_slug=comp_slug, hidden=False).order_by('group_name')

    # Initialize an empty form to create a new group (to be displayed in a modal)
    group_form = GroupDetail()
    group_form.fields['all_users'].queryset = UserComp.objects.\
                                                filter(company=company).\
                                                order_by('user__last_name', 'user__first_name')


    return render(request, "polls/adm_groups.html", locals())
```

As you can see, I generate an empty form at this stage to ease the display when the user intends to create a new item.
In this case, **the modal works perfectly**. Unfortunately, I need to use the script to refresh the form if I have edited another item before; and, in this case, like you will see, it doesn't work.

To populate the form to edit an object, data is gathered thanks to a js script:
The script to generate the form is the following:

```js
    $('.update-grp').click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: $(this).attr('url-endpoint'),
            data: {
                comp_slug: $(this).attr('comp-slug'),
                grp_id: $(this).attr('grp-id')
            },
            success: handleSuccess,
            error: handleError,
        });

        function handleSuccess(data) {
            $(".form_content").html(data.group_form);
        };

        function handleError(error_data) {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(error_data);
        };
    })
```

It calls the following view:

```py
def get_group_detail(request):
    """ Gather and send information related to groups """

    comp_slug = request.GET["comp_slug"]
    grp_id = int(request.GET["grp_id"])   # comes as string when 0
    company = Company.get_company(comp_slug)

    if grp_id > 0:
        current_group = UserGroup.objects.get(id=grp_id)
        group_form = GroupDetail(instance=current_group)
    else:
        group_form = GroupDetail()
        group_form.fields['all_users'].queryset = UserComp.objects.\
                                                    filter(company=company).\
                                                    order_by('user__last_name', 'user__first_name')

    context = {
        "comp_slug": comp_slug,
        "company": company,
        "grp_id": grp_id,
        "group_form": group_form,
    }

    template = render_to_string('polls/adm_group_detail.html', context=context, request=request)

    return JsonResponse({"group_form": template})
```

The modal is displayed properly but **the scripts related to the form are not launched at all** (even a `console.log('Hello')` do no display anything).

Among my tries, one of them was to generate the whole template not only, the one dedicated to the form, but the result was just worse.

For your information, I don't know it it could help, here is a view of the modal with data:
[image]

Blue buttons are designed to move elements from one list to the other, which is also possible thanks to a double click. But nothing happens at all within the modal.

Comment: So your data is not loading into the modal form rgt?

Comment: Yes it is, as the latest screenshot presents

Comment: And you are loading/updating the data using ajax call have you checked your console?

Comment: Yes I did, no real relevant message

Comment: the problem would be in get_group_detail .. are you getting your responses in ajax?

Comment: did you added the update-grp function at the right place?

Comment: 'are you getting your responses in ajax?' => I think so, as the display is correct (and the initial form is empty) - 'did you added the update-grp function at the right place?' => could you please detail ? Not sure what you have in mind, I did not define any 'update-grp' function but the 'click' function dedicated to the related button is at root level, just embedded by `$(document).ready(function()` like all other ones

Comment: Not a direct fix for you but you may be interested to know htmx.org exists, specifically: https://htmx.org/examples/modal-custom/

Comment: @AMG thanks, looks nice, I've already read about it =) I also discovered the new js function [fetch()](https://fr.javascript.info/fetch) but not supported yet by all web browsers, and I feel not advanced enough to manage this, I would like for the time being to be able to manage more mature tools

Comment: First post edited: shall I nead to make a kind of 'reload' of JS scripts? When I look at the Inspector, I have (almost) the same page, except that events disappeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I latest felt was correct: the scripts do not apply to updated html code. To change this, I need to attach the handler to a parent object that will not change, then 'delegate' to the actual object that is supposed to trigger an action.

Thus, I need to change how the buttons in the modal are triggered end replace this, where the handler is on the button itself:

```js
$("#add_selected").on("click", function(e) {
```

with this, where the handler includes the modal, and delegate the event to the button:

```js
$(".form_content").on("click", '#add_selected', function(e) {
```